# Can a pyspark window be created based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I've got a dataframe that I want to partition for analysis. It has an asset column that can be used for the partition. Also, it has a seq_start column that is either true or null. When we order the timestamp for each asset, the seq start column indicates that the readings from the seq start (True) to the next start are part of one batch. The length is not always the same. There may be up to 10 nulls between two ordered starts (True), or no nulls. I want to partition and either group or collect all reading values in the reading column based on the asset and seq_start columns.

| timestamp | asset | reading | seq_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-09T05:01:57 | asset_1 | 4 | True |
| 2023-06-09T05:05:20 | asset_1 | 5 | null |
| 2023-06-09T05:11:52 | asset_1 | 1 | null |
| 2023-06-09T05:20:50 | asset_1 | 3 | True |
| 2023-06-09T07:03:26 | asset_2 | 4 | True |
| 2023-06-09T07:21:24 | asset_2 | 6 | True |
| 2023-06-09T07:23:57 | asset_2 | 8 | null |
| 2023-06-09T07:40:58 | asset_2 | 2 | null |

I know I can use rowsbetween, but unfortunately, the partition sizes are unequal. Is there a way to partition this or use another method to solve this? I'm hoping to get a partition similar to this:

| timestamp | asset | reading | seq_start | partition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-09T05:01:57 | asset_1 | 4 | True | 1 |
| 2023-06-09T05:05:20 | asset_1 | 5 | null | 1 |
| 2023-06-09T05:11:52 | asset_1 | 1 | null | 1 |
| 2023-06-09T05:20:50 | asset_1 | 3 | True | 2 |
| 2023-06-09T07:03:26 | asset_2 | 4 | True | 3 |
| 2023-06-09T07:21:24 | asset_2 | 6 | True | 4 |
| 2023-06-09T07:23:57 | asset_2 | 8 | null | 4 |
| 2023-06-09T07:40:58 | asset_2 | 2 | null | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the partition over the entire dataframe you should assign partition values per assset for efficiency and to avoid memory overflow issues. Basically group the dataframe by asset and arder by timestamp then calculate cumulative sum over the `seq_start`

```
W = Window.partitionBy('asset').orderBy('timestamp')
df = df.withColumn('partition', F.sum(F.col('seq_start').cast('int')).over(W))
```

---

```
+-------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|          timestamp|  asset|reading|seq_start|partition|
+-------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|2023-06-09T05:01:57|asset_1|      4|     true|        1|
|2023-06-09T05:05:20|asset_1|      5|     null|        1|
|2023-06-09T05:11:52|asset_1|      1|     null|        1|
|2023-06-09T05:20:50|asset_1|      3|     true|        2|
|2023-06-09T07:03:26|asset_2|      4|     true|        1|
|2023-06-09T07:21:24|asset_2|      6|     true|        2|
|2023-06-09T07:23:57|asset_2|      8|     null|        2|
|2023-06-09T07:40:58|asset_2|      2|     null|        2|
+-------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```